# Create dynamic wordpress blank page

Tags: admin-menu, add-submenu-page

I've created a submenu in WordPress using add_submenu_page:

```php
add_submenu_page(null,'Page Title','Page Title','administrator','page-slug','page-callback');
```

I want to create another page like this with the condition that the page will be totally blank without creating a new file, does WordPress have a function like this? I want it because I want to generate and download an XML file there and if the page has headers and footers the page downloads them too. Any Suggestion? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this: in the load hook, you can ouput your xml code. 
u

```
function my_menu_pages() {
    $hook = add_submenu_page(
            null, 'Page Title', 'Page Title', 'administrator', 'sub-menu-slug', function() {
    }
    );
    add_action('load-' . $hook, function() {
        // add your xml code here, 
        // you will get a blank page to start with
        exit;
    });
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_pages');
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to do this with admin menus/ admin pages. It is going to be a headache. Set up an [AJAX API callback](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and you can have complete control of the  output with no worries about any other markup since there won't be any.

```
function download_xml_wpse_144156() {
  // generate your XML and echo it
  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_grab_my_xml', 'download_xml_wpse_144156');
add_action('wp_ajax_grab_my_xml', 'download_xml_wpse_144156');
```

You can retrieve the XML file with a request to `//example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=grab_my_xml`. Note that `grab_my_xml` is the trailing part of the two action hooks. You can set that to whatever you like.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work for me maybe i am using it wrong

Comment: Yes, you must be using this incorrectly. It does work.

Answer (score 1):

Add blank page without wordpress functionality, so you can add your own custom content and controls using your own markup.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );
        function my_admin_menu() {
            add_menu_page( 'Page Title', 'Menu Name', 'manage_options', 'page_menu_slug', 'page_function', 'dashicons-carrot', 6 );
            add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
        }
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: @fuxia, updated

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/306416/27278), here's an implementation example with OOP:

1. Create `Admin.php` file:

```php
class Admin {
  public function register_admin_pages() {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'admin_menu_callback' ] );
  }

  public function admin_menu_callback() {
    add_menu_page( __( 'My Page', 'my-translation' ), __( 'My Page', 'my-translation' ), 'manage_options', 'my_menu', [ $this, 'render_my_page' ], 'dashicons-carrot', 25 );
  }


  public function render_test_failures_page() {
    include __DIR__ . '/my-page.php';
  }
}
```

2. Create file `my-page.php` that will have the HTML. For example purposes, the following HTML will generate this result:

```php
// You can add <style></style> tags here if you wish
<div class="wrap">
    <h1 class="wp-heading-inline">My Page</h1>
    <a href="#" class="page-title-action">Some Action</a>
    <hr class="wp-header-end">
    <p>My Page Contents</p>
    <div class="card">
        <p>My Page Contents Inside div.card</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: wordpress register custom admin page]

3. On your plugin main file, call:

```php
require_once( __DIR__ . '/Admin.php' );
$admin = new Admin;
$admin->register_admin_pages();
```